# http - client server - request response - connection

Tags: http, client-server

I've been reading about HTTP protocol. The description says, 
"HTTP functions as a request-response protocol in the client-server computing model".

So, my question is, "should Client-Server model always follow Request-Response Protocol? and the vice-versa is true?"

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can servers request a response from a client? Well.. no.. I mean.. maybe. But that would contradict the definition of the server and client relationship.

Of course there are acknowledgements - for when a packet is recieved - that the client sends the server, but that's at the TCP level.

At least that's my understanding.

Comment: the question was more about how tightly coupled are the "client-server model" and "request-response protocol".?